# php: laravel Storage / File append vs file_put_contents

Tags: laravel, file, append

I'm trying to merge a file chunked in parts and in Laravel Framework 7.30.4 is not working the append method of Storage/File Facade

```
        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            $content = Storage::get($file);
            Storage::append($tmp_file, $content);
        }
```

When I do it with vanilla php works fine:

```
        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            $content = Storage::get($file);
            file_put_contents(storage_path("app/{$tmp_file}"), $content, FILE_APPEND);
        }
```

the md5 hash results is only correct with the vanilla style, what I'm doing wrong in laravel style?

I'm watching with **vbindiff** tool and the all the file is equal except the last part.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this code in laravel code:

```
    public function append($path, $data, $separator = PHP_EOL)
    {
        if ($this->exists($path)) {
            return $this->put($path, $this->get($path).$separator.$data);
        }

        return $this->put($path, $data);
    }
```

Solved using NULL as separator:

```
        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            $content = Storage::get($file);
            Storage::append($tmp_file, $content, NULL);
        }
```